# Clone HDD to readable format (iso)?

Tags: windows, backup, clone

I'm planning on reinstalling tomorrow and I'd like to backup my c: onto my big spinning disk so I can pull the files I want.

I really don't want to use a 3rd party software to restore the files I want.  Is there any software that could copy it to an iso other widely accessible file format?

I've already got windows 10 on the machine. I'm upgrading the motherboard and CPU, so I want to start with a fresh install of windows (this one has been being upgraded since 2009).

Comment: What OS? Use the tags to add your OS so we can give you a better answer :) - If you use Windows as of Vista then you can take a WIM (using WinPE/DISM) which then be opened using 7-Zip.

Comment: Using DVD's for a backup may be awkward due to having to span the files across multiple DVD's (Assuming that by the term 'spinning disk' you mean DVD) - Can you use a USB HDD instead?

Comment: Not using DVDs.  I just want to clone it to an image file that I can access with the normal tools I use and not a disk utility

Comment: What version of Windows... important detail to questions will yield better quality answers!

Comment: Hmm..  Norton Ghost or Macrium Reflect..  Sounds like you are putting the cart before the horse.  This is like saying Can I restore my system from a backup without an OS there?  No.

Comment: Here is the other thing you are going to have to watch for..  Do you have a VL version of Windows?  Most consumer version of Windows is 1 license to one device.  If you want to image your OS, you are going to only be able to use it on the same device unless you have VL Key.